# What is the limit of the sequence $x_n = \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

With all the methods that I've tried I always get $0 \cdot \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) = \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) \frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$. And therefore,...

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Note that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_n = \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=\sqrt{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\sim_\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: Instead of using an equivalent (which isn't that obvious because for the denominator you need the equivalent of a sum), I'd rather divide both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an alterative approach:

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right) &= \sqrt{n(n+1)}-n\\ &= \sqrt{n^2+n+1/4} -n + \sqrt{n(n+1)}-\sqrt{n^2+n+1/4} \\&=\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{n(n+1)}-\sqrt{n^2+n+1/4}
\end{align} $$

Now just show that $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+1/4}\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.